# How to do arithmetic operations in ejs?

Tags: css, ejs

How can I perform arithmetic operations inside ejs template.I am trying to style my images giving them proper height and width.For setting the width I am trying to get the total number of images from an array of images.**I am setting the width = (1/total_no_of_images)% so that each image takes equal width**.I am unable to do this operation inside ejs.

```
var num = 1/<%= Restaurant.photos.length %>
```

where `"Restaurant.photos.length"` represents number of images in photos array.

and later setting `"width:num%"` using inline css**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using <% %> instead of <%= %>.

```
<% var num = 1 / Restaurant.photos.length %>
```

Here value will be store in num and you can use it. Like:

```
<h1><%= num %></h1>
```